# Workaround for missing child dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

My pom.xml has a dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>baz</artifactId>
  <version>9.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If I navigate inside the repo I'm using, I see that the jar file is there.  If I look at the pom for that jar, it has a dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>biff</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If I navigate inside the repo I'm using, I see that the source jar file is there, but the compiled jar is not.

Assuming I cannot make any modifications to the maven repo, is there anything I can do to get this working?  Can I download the source, compile it and point to it locally?

Comment: You can do what you suggest. But the only right way is to understand why the compiled jar is  missing. A repository should contain the artifact without any doubt and optionally the sources. You are in the reverse situation.

Comment: You can try `mvn -U dependency:resolve` to force Maven to redownload all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and downloaded the source, compiled and pointed to it locally.